# How to animate a UITableViewCell on edit?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

How do you animate a color change in table view cells when a user taps the a table view's edit button?

When the edit button is tapped, Apple's animation shifts the contents of all the cells right to display a delete or insert button in each cell.  I'd like to add my own animations that occur simultaneously with Apple's.  I've managed to animate the cell layout but not color changes.

This is what I'm doing:

```
override func willTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
    super.willTransition(to: state)

    let willEdit = state.contains(.showingEditControlMask)

    toDateDaysLayoutConstraint.constant = willEdit ? 5.0 : 25.0
    daysNightsLayoutConstraint.constant = willEdit ? 5.0 : 10.0

    toDateTextView.textColor = willEdit ? UIColor.red : UIColor.darkText
    daysLabel.backgroundColor = willEdit ? UIColor.cyan : UIColor.clear        
}
```

To be clear, the above layoutConstraint changes animate properly, but the colors change instantaneously without animation.

I've also tried to animate the color using UIView block animations as follows:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0) { 
        self.toDateTextView.textColor = willEdit ? UIColor.red : UIColor.darkText
        self.daysLabel.backgroundColor = willEdit ? UIColor.cyan : UIColor.clear
    }
```

But, I can never get the color to animate.  I've tried putting the above code in `willTransition(to state:)`, `setEditing(_ editing: animated:)`, even `layoutSubviews()`.  I've also tried it in the table controller methods.  But, nothing works.

---

**UPDATE**

By now, I've also tried wrapping everything between `CATransaction.begin()` and `CATransaction.commit()`, also using only layer animations, and even putting the `commit` in `didTransition` after the call to `super`.  Nothing works.

I'm wondering, is it possible to do any animation simultaneously with Apple's that's not a layout animation?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you can only animate "animatable" properties of a UIView (see [this list](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)). `textColor` isn't in it. I've used `UIView.transition(with:duration:options:animations)` in place and the text color is "animated" properly:

```
override func willTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {

    super.willTransition(to: state)

    UIView.transition(with: textLabel!, duration: 5.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.textLabel?.textColor = state.rawValue == 1 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.black
    })
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Following your comment, I've managed to reproduce the issue. I fixed it for the `UILabel` by overriding `didTransition(to:)` instead of `willTransition(to:)`. So we first wait for the views to be resized (because of the appearing delete button) and then we animate. However, this does not work very well for the `UITextView`, unless you make sure it has a fixed size.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func didTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {

        super.didTransition(to: state)

        UIView.transition(with: textView, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.textView.textColor = state.rawValue == 1 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.black
        })

        UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.label.backgroundColor = state.rawValue == 1 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.white
        })
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If you need your text view to be resizable then execute the animation asynchronously:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    UIView.transition(with: self.textView, duration: 3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.textView.textColor = state.rawValue == 1 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.black
    })
}
```

By the way, I also tried to subclass `UITextView` and override `layoutSubviews` but it did not work...

Comment: This is nice.  Finally a color animation working!  But, it doesn't quite work yet.  Now there's a double image of the text label caused, I guess, by 2 independent animations.  The text label in black is moving and fading out, while a separate red label appears in a different position fading in.  Even if I try to match the timing to Apple's animation, it still seems fuzzy.  And, for the backgroundColor animation, even matching the timing, you still see a double image of the label.

Comment: +1 for the textColor animation.  Thanks for all the suggestions!  But, the main question is still unanswered:  how can you do a color animation _simultaneously_ with Apple's?  Or is it not possible?  I'll leave the question open to see if anyone can come up with an answer to that.

Comment: @salo.dm You mean a color animation simultaneously to the cell's transition?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Just like changing layout constraints in `willTransition`.  Those changes are animated simultaneously with Apple's animation for the appearing button.  So, how to animate color simultaneously with the appearing button?